# Show next and previous page number

Tags: pagination

Anyone who knows how to show the previous and next page number? I've been searching a tutorial for this but I can't seem to find one. Basically, I want my pagination to be like this:

for example, user is currently on page 2 so the page navigation should be like this:

← 01 previous /  03 next →

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

How about using the built-in function?

```
<?php
previous_post_link( '%link', '' . _x( '&larr;', 'Previous post link', 'twentyten' ) . ' %title' );
next_post_link( '%link', '%title ' . _x( '&rarr;', 'Next post link', 'twentyten' ) . '' );
?>
```

More information on pagination is available here:

- [Pagination](https://codex.wordpress.org/Pagination)
- [the_posts_pagination](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_posts_pagination)